# rails how to start from breakpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

i have an array around 2000 record(objects)

and want to do start from breakpoint if i had an error

for example

`arr` - all elements

```
arr.each_with_index do |el,i| 

User.create(params from el)
end
```

and i have received an error on 221 record so i want to start from 222

after break

```
arr(222).each_with_index do |el,i| 

User.create(params from el)
end
```

and so on

So my question is how to save index of my array without db?

or its imposible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
unprocessable_indexes = []

arr.each_with_index do |el, i| 
    begin
        User.find_or_create_by!(params from el)
    rescue
        unprocessable_indexes.push(i)
    end
end

puts unprocessable_indexes
```

The code above will logs all errors index of your array into `unprocessable_indexes` array, and won't break your program in the middle of the process as well.

From `unprocessable_indexes` variable, you could now find out what cause a problem in a clear location of your array.

You could also fix the bad data, and re-run the code again and again without harming your existing data as well.

Hope this helps :)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using begin-rescue to catch the exception.

`arr.each_with_index do |el,i| 
  begin
   User.create(params from el)
  resque
   puts i
end`

On this resque you print the i (index) on your console. You can play with this to reload your function starting with this index.